# Поиск данных в промежутке 2-х datepicker-ов и их вывод

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, datepicker

Есть список данных которые выводятся в DataGrid из sql, нужно отфильтровать данные в промежутке одной даты по вторую дату.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: окей, и в чем проблема? составь sql запрос с использованием `between` и выведи полученные результаты

Comment: SQL запрос выглядит по аналогии с ответом на вопрос по ссылке: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36892588/13123688. Для того, чтобы взять дату из DateTimePicker используйте свойство Value. Так же можете воспользоваться свойством Ticks.